# How to present webpage just like email composer with in the app

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a table view with list of we site addresses.

**I have implemented to open website with url existing in cell Text, by clicking on a respective cell**

as follows:

---

```
NSURL *websiteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:cell.textLabel.text];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:websiteURL];
```

---

assume http://mywebsite.com" is the text on my cell

*

```
NSURL *websiteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:websiteURL];
```

*

it **opens the correct web page but it quits my active application, and opens safari app**

I was **unable to came bak to my application again with out quit the webpage**.

So ***`I need to present webpage with in the app just like MF Emil composer.`***

As `all we know MF Emil composer opens mail page and return back to active application, when click on cancel button.`

I need same like MF Emil composer present model.

Comment: NSURL *websiteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:websiteURL]; this line of code will open the link in your safari. So what you can do is have separate ViewController just to show the link. On click of cell you load the ViewController and in that ViewController you should have UIWebView to load the link in UIWebView that way you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

-> Create the new view controller.

-> Add webview as a subview of the view controller.

Eg:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)];  
webView.delegate = self;

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mywebsite.com"] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval: myTimeoutValue];  
[self.webView loadRequest: request];
```

->then Present the new view controller from where you want to call the url.